# Как проверить играет ли Media player в Android?

Tags: android, mediaplayer, android-mediaplayer

Для условия нужно проверить играет ли что то в медиа плеере, как это можно сделать?
P.s Если не сложно посоветуйте пожалуйста где я могу находить данную информацию на русском языке.

Попытался сделать так

```
MediaPlayer mp; 
......



 switch (v.getId()) {

        case (R.id.Dbutton):

                if (mp.isPlaying()) {}
                    mp.stop();
                else
        {
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dbsound);
                    mp.start();
                }
```

Но все руиниться с ошибкой

isPlaying()' on a null object reference

Comment: У Вас есть пример Вашей попытки реализации/проверки? На данном проекте принято сначала выкладывать свои неудавшиеся попытки, а потом задавать вопросы, иначе вопрос рискует быть неотвеченным.

Comment: Ну добавьте проверку на `null`: `if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying())` либо разберитесь почему `mp` не инициализирован в момент нажатия кнопки если такого быть не должно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)